# Does it make a difference where you add a sheet or alert in swiftui?

Tags: swiftui

Modal views seem to work almost anywhere you add them, but does it matter where you put an alert, actionsheet, sheet or fullsheet in siwftui? Does it affect accessibility, maybe? Or is it a matter of clarity to put it closer to where you activate it (for example put an actionsheet about deleting a row on the list itself, next to the onDelete)?

For example, without knowing the context, does it make a difference where I add it here (1, 2, 3, 4)?:

```swift
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(array, id: \.self) { i in
                Text(i) // <= HERE 1
            } // <= HERE 2
            Button(action: {
                showSheet = true
            }) {
                Text("Present sheet")
            } // <= HERE 3
        } // <= HERE 4
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SwiftUI gets very picky about how sheets are presented in the hierarchy, so there's at least one important scenario where it matters.

Consider the following example:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State var showSheet1 = false
    @State var showSheet2 = false
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(["Hi", "There"], id: \.self) { i in
                Text(i)
            }
            Button(action: {
                showSheet1 = true
            }) {
                Text("Present sheet 1")
            }.sheet(isPresented: $showSheet1) {
                Text("Sheet 1")
            }
            Button(action: { showSheet2 = true }) {
                Text("Present sheet 2")
            }.sheet(isPresented: $showSheet2) {
                Text("Sheet 2")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In that example, both sheet 1 and sheet 2 will be successfully presented when their respective buttons are pressed.

Example 2:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State var showSheet1 = false
    @State var showSheet2 = false
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(["Hi", "There"], id: \.self) { i in
                Text(i)
            }
            Button(action: {
                showSheet1 = true
            }) {
                Text("Present sheet 1")
            }.sheet(isPresented: $showSheet1) {
                Text("Sheet 1")
            }
            Button(action: { showSheet2 = true }) {
                Text("Present sheet 2")
            }
        }.sheet(isPresented: $showSheet2) {
            Text("Sheet 2")
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, sheet 2 is still successfully presented, but sheet 1 is not.

In the first example, both siblings had sheets and didn't have a common ancestor. In example 2, the common parent causes an issue.

So, to answer your question, yes, it does matter where the sheet is added, at least under the circumstances that there may be multiple sheets in the hierarchy.

One way to avoid this particular issue would be to just have one sheet presenter and use `sheet(item:)` to determine *which* sheet would be presented and then tack it onto an outside parent view.

If I can, I try to make the code easily readable and understandable by doing this like you referenced in your question (like the action sheet attached to the list). However, there are times when (because of the issue I mentioned) I end up using more of a 'global' (term used lightly here) solution by attaching everything as high up the hierarchy as I can comfortably go.